# tsch syntax error:unecxpected end of file when using while loop to read lines

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

We have been trying to get a script to work in tcsh (i know that most places say that it should no be used but i don't think i have a choice).

The script should take in a file with columns and remove identical lines but add how many of them there is. We are new to tsch and a have trouble getting the syntax right. It is extra confusing by all the similar but still different syntax that seems to exist for the different shells.

It seems that something isn't closed as it should but we have tried any kind of combination of fi,endif, done and end for if and while loop. Removing the if cases doesn't solve problem and neither does removing what is outside the while loop. Could the issue be how we used read?

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' raw_data|
awk -v OFS=' -> ' '{$1=$1};1'| sort -k 3 > collapsed_output.txt

number=0
lastline=0
while ( read -r collapsed_output.txt )
    do 
    line = $line
    if ( line == lastline )
        then
        number=number+1
    else if( number != 0 ) 
        then sed -i 'ls/^/lastline + ["label =" number] \n/' numbered_data.txt
        number=1
        lastline = line
    else
        number = 1
        lastline = line
    fi
done
sed -i 'ls/^/lastline + ["label =" number] \n/' numbered_data.txt
sed -i '1s/^/digraph finite_state_machine {\n/' numbered_data.txt
sed -i '$ a\'"}" numbered_data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code as posted has another error: if you try to run it, the error message would be “Invalid null command.”. Always post the exact code that you used (it should have started with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, too). And copy-paste the error message — a typo (“unecxpected”) in something you should have copy-pasted is inexcusable.

If you really want to use tcsh (and you probably don't have to — a Bourne/POSIX-style shell is available everywhere tcsh is, and usually you even have either ksh or bash), you need to use tcsh features, not sh features. Instead of trying things blindly, read the manual. It wouldn't have solved all your problems, but it does explain how to write a `while` loop.

One feature of sh that also exists in tcsh is the `-x` option to print a trace of lines as they are executed. This will at least reveal where the error is — it's just after the line that was successfully parsed and executed.

“Invalid null command.” is due to the first code line: you can't put a newline after a pipe (unlike in sh). You need a backslash for a line continuation, or put everything on the same line.

You can't put a bare assignment in csh — `number=0` tries to invoke a command called `number=0`, and `line = $line` tries to invoke a command called `line` (that one is also the case in sh!). Assignments can be written `@ VARIABLE = EXPRESSION` for numbers, `set VARIABLE="VALUE"` for strings.

The syntax of a [`while` loop](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#while) is `while (EXPRESSION) INSTRUCTIONS… wend`. There is no `do` or `done` keyword. Furthermore what's in the parenthesis needs to be an expression; to use the [return status of an instruction as the value of an expression](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Command_exit_status.html), put the instruction in braces.

`read` is a Bourne command, it doesn't exist in tcsh. You get the same functionality from reading the [`$<` variable](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Variable_substitution.html), except that as far as I know you can't detect the end of the file (it's indistinguishable from an empty line), which makes it impossible to read a file in a loop. Another option to read lines from standard input is

```
foreach line ("`cat`")
  …
end
```

but note that this skips empty lines and mangles backslashes.

There's some strange logic in your loop — I don't understand what it's trying to do, and the invalid sed commands (did you mean `1s` instead of `ls`?) aren't helping.

I recommend writing this script in a sh instead, since you seem more familiar with it.